# Update record using MySQL, Entity Framework + Ext.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ext.net

I have a snippet of code that I can't quite get to work:

```
StoreDataHandler dataHandler = new StoreDataHandler(HttpContext.Request["data"]);
ChangeRecords<ChequeDiary> data = dataHandler.ObjectData<ChequeDiary>();

foreach (ChequeDiary item in data.Updated) {
    db.ChequeDiaries.Attach(item);
    db.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.ClientWins, item);
}
```

This is meant to get the changes and update the underlying object but when I call

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

.. nothing is updated. If I use:

```
foreach (ChequeDiary item in data.Updated) {
    ChequeDiary obj = db.ChequeDiaries.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == item.Id);
    obj.BankedAmount = item.BankedAmount;
}
```

and explicity set each property, it works. Why?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example likely doesn't mark any properties as modified. Check the `ObjectStateManager` to confirm this. In general, you must modify properties *after* you attach the object.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I just expected it to know that from the data it was passed. Cheers for clearing it up.